# C++ Set as startup program

Tags: c++, windows, registry

I have a program in C++ which I want to run on Windows startup. I want to create a new string value on Windows registry at

```
            HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run**
```

How can I do that using code?

Comment: You should add a Windows service that points to your program instead. Also, this question, as it currently is, has no usefulness. Voted to close.

Comment: @ray, that depends.  Lots of programs really do want to launch automatically in the user's own context, when the user logs in, and the Run key is perfectly good for that.  You only need a service for code that have to run when no users are logged in, or that have to run with administrative privilege.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: While I agree with you, the OP didn't specify any of those details, so the assumed goal is, for the most part, a guess. The OP also didn't show what he/she had tried before, which is generally another no-no here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using WinApi functions to manipulate registry keys, see here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724875%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

In particular RegOpenKey, RegSetKeyValue, RegCloseKey.

Note that to do that under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE the app needs to be run with elevated permissions. For HKEY_CURRENT_USER the app can do that with the regular user permissions.